# Can't add actions/buttons to PUSH notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the Firebase [Admin SDK (Java)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference) to send push notifications to Android devices.
This all is working fine.

I'm looking to add an action button for notifications.
[Example from this of desired outcome](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/05/web-notifications-api-support-now.html) (which is for web push)

**Problem**

I can't find anything in the SDK to add **actions** to a notifications.

Has anyone used actions to create buttons for push notification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Android App. If you want you can create an Intent based on information that came from the notification:

What really matters for you is the part when I create the NotificationCompat.Action.

```
private void showPushNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    int requestCode = (int) (Math.random()*3000);
    int id = (int) (Math.random()*300000);
    String channelId = "fcm_defaul_channel_id"; // FIXME: set channelId
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Bitmap iconLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18);

    // title and body
    title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title"); //or remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()
    body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body"); or remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()
    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    // create action send sms
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
            0, "action test", pendingIntent ).build();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_full_open_on_phone) // FIXME: change images
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(smsMessageIntent)
                    .addAction(action);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
    } else { // FIXME: eliminare dopo i test
        Log.d(TAG, "notificationManager null");
        Toast.makeText(this, "notificationManager null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using the server side [SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference). Trying to figure out how I can driver actions _(if possible)_ from the notification to the App. Like how it is done is this [Web Push[(https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/05/web-notifications-api-support-now.html) example. Your code is running on the App, I'm looking to get the action/button displayed based on the server side code to generate the push message.